# How to bootstrap the time series data for assets portfolio mean - variance optimization?

Tags: time-series, econometrics, bootstrap, resampling

As known among professionals and amateur investors, the classical Markovitz portfolio mean - variance optimization yields very unstable results that perform poorly in the real world.

One of the approaches to solve this problem is to bootstrap the assets prices data, run the optimization function several hundreds times, then average the results and use them. Of course, the prices time series are not independent, so bootstrapping this data is not trivial.

How would you perform the time series bootstrap in this case for practical purposes? Let's suppose that we have 3-8 assets, about 8 years of data (2000 trading days) available.

Is moving block bootstrap OK? What should be the size of the blocks? Can they intersect or not? I would appreciate the code in Python or R.

Also, is it a good idea to bootstrap financial time series for calculating the annualized Sharp ratio or correlation between assets? If yes, how to do it properly?